# Blink/Flash label if certain criteria met

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class

```
    public class LabelContainer:WebControl
    {
    private Label myLable= new Label();
    private TextBox t = new TextBox();


    public void FlashControl()
    {
     myLable.Text = 15;
      If (Int16.Parse(myLable.text)>10)
      {
       myLable.Visible =! myLable.Visible
      }
      else
      {
       _Label.Visible
      } 
    }
}
```

And i am 'new'ing it up on default page on every tick of master page timer. Master page has a timer and has a tick event. Master page timer is in update panel with AsyncPostBackTrigger and ContentTemplate (it just display time on master and all pages, i am not sure its relevant).

```
var label = new LabelContainer();
label.FlashControl();
```

On every tick the 'new'ing up happens but Control Doesn't Blink. It either stays visible if text is < 10 or stays invisible if text > 10. Is there any way i can make this label to blink if it meets certain criteria? Or any other substitute for this (if its without jquery or java script would be great)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should use Javascript.

Comment: would it be possible if you can give me example? reason this control is dynamic and i dont know how i should work with java script